# When i move the mouse on my page in Internet explorer there is a high cpu utilization why is it happening?

Tags: internet-explorer

i created a page where there is a jstree and huge set of data. When i move the mouse pointer in the page there is a high cpu utilization why is this happening?

Comment: Which version IE ? Early IE (before 9) has a (sorry to say it) rubbish javascript engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jstree has a pretty extensive `mousemove` handler, `$.vakata.dnd.drag` which could be the culprit. There could be other mouse move handlers in the code as well.

It's most likely related to IE's poor JS performance and a large number of operations in a mouse move handler which would fire many times a second while moving the mouse.